# autocomplete rails routes issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm using the [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) gem for an rfq model to search customers. The autocomplete search works fine when I'm creating a new rfq, but I get this error when I try to use the search while editing a record.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/rfqs/1/autocomplete_customer_name"):
```

I know what the error means but I'm not familiar enough with the routing to fix it.

Thank you ahead of time for the help

```
 resources :rfqs do
    get :autocomplete_customer_name, :on => :collection
    member do
      put :toggle
    end
  end

  resources :customers do
    get :autocomplete_company_name, :on => :collection
  end

  resources :companies
```

Comment: Can you include your routes in the post?

Comment: @steveklein I forgot earlier, just added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a member route for this to work (since you are trying to access "/rfqs/1/autocomplete_customer_name"):

```
get :autocomplete_customer_name, :on => :member
```

Member routes add an :id param in the route, while the collection routes work without id params:

```
resources :items do
  get :foo, on: :member
  get :bar, on: :collection
end

# will create folowing routes:
# items/:id/foo
# items/bar
```

Comment: So what does :on => collection do?

Comment: I added a short explanation to the answer